# How do I force Mediasoup to use vp9 codec?

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, vp9, mediasoup

We have an installation of Mediasoup working without problems. We are using a mediasoup version that is compatible with vp9 codec. The issue we have is that it uses h.264 codec by default and we run on bandwidth constrained environments and we need to use VP9. How can we force Mediasoup to always use VP9?

Could we do it forcing Chrome to request a VP9 connection?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found how to do it and it is quite easy on the Mediasoup demo. We just need to append this parameter to the URL: forceVP9=true

Comment: Where do we force that, which url?